# GDPR Extension on CiviCRM-WordPress: acceptance checkbox not showing up on registration forms

Tags: civievent, forms, registration, gdpr

I have installed GDPR Extension on a CiviCRM running on WordPress in order to include the acceptance checkbox in a event register form.

I have followed all recommended steps to configure it (GPDR Dashboard) and checked to activate it in my event. But when I try online register, it shows up nothing. Privacy Police and acceptance checkbox are still missing.

[image: terms and conditions tab GDPR Extension]
[image: terms and conditions not showing up]

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be wellcome.

Sandra

Comment: 1. Are you seeing any errors in your browser console?
2. What versions of gdpr and civicrm you using?
3. Do you notice anything different if the registration url is from backend backend (with wp-admin in url)?
I'm "deepaks" on civicrm chat. I'm doing some gdpr work today. If you there i can go through your site to see if we find the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Also check https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/issues/92, might help.